# Subscriptions in GraphQL in ASP.NET Core. How do I switch to SubscriptionDocumentExecuter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

Ok I am perplexed.
After following long tutorial installing Nuget package : "GraphQL.SystemReactive" and "GraphQL.Server.Transports.Subscriptions.WebSockets".

I receive a message on GraphQL Playground that subscription are no longer supported

```
DocumentExecuter does not support executing subscriptions. You can use SubscriptionDocumentExecuter from GraphQL.SystemReactive package to handle subscriptions. occurred"
```

I have no idea how I can switch DocumentExecuter? In Schema or Subscription there is no such method to override:

```
protected override IExecutionStrategy SelectExecutionStrategy(ExecutionContext context)
{
    return context.Operation.OperationType switch
    {
        OperationType.Subscription => SubscriptionExecutionStrategy.Instance,
        _ => base.SelectExecutionStrategy(context)
    };
}
```

How do I fix this?  This is my Schema

```
public class DragonSchema : Schema
{
    private readonly DragonShopDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly OpinionMessageService _messageService;


    public DragonSchema(DragonShopDbContext dbContext,
        OpinionMessageService messageService,
        IServiceProvider sp) : base(sp)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _messageService = messageService;

        Subscription = new DragonSubscription(_messageService);

        Query = new DragonQuery
           (new DragonRepository(_dbContext));

        Mutation = new DragonMutation(
            new DragonExpertOpinionRepository(_dbContext),
            _messageService);
    }
}
```

This is my subscription definition:

```
public class DragonSubscription : ObjectGraphType
{
    public DragonSubscription(OpinionMessageService messageService)
    {
        Name = "Subscription";
        AddField(new EventStreamFieldType
        {
            Name = "opinionAdded",
            Type = typeof(OpinionAddedMessageType),

            Resolver = new FuncFieldResolver<OpinionAddedMessage>
            (c => c.Source as OpinionAddedMessage),

            Subscriber = new EventStreamResolver<OpinionAddedMessage>
            (c => messageService.GetMessages())
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok
You don't need to create your Middleware or Controller to deal with this.

DocumentExecuter does not support executing subscriptions as you can see in the code.

```
protected virtual IExecutionStrategy SelectExecutionStrategy(ExecutionContext context)
{
    // TODO: Should we use cached instances of the default execution strategies?
    return context.Operation.OperationType switch
    {
        OperationType.Query => ParallelExecutionStrategy.Instance,
        OperationType.Mutation => SerialExecutionStrategy.Instance,
        OperationType.Subscription => throw new NotSupportedException($"DocumentExecuter does not support executing subscriptions. You can use SubscriptionDocumentExecuter from GraphQL.SystemReactive package to handle subscriptions."),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected OperationType {context.Operation.OperationType}")
    };
}
```

I just create my version of the DocumentExecuter that don't throw this Exception.

```
public class MyDocumentExecuter : DocumentExecuter, IDocumentExecuterSub
{
    protected override IExecutionStrategy SelectExecutionStrategy(ExecutionContext context)
    {
        return context.Operation.OperationType switch
        {
            OperationType.Query => ParallelExecutionStrategy.Instance,
            OperationType.Mutation => SerialExecutionStrategy.Instance,
            OperationType.Subscription => SubscriptionExecutionStrategy.Instance,
            _ => base.SelectExecutionStrategy(context)
        };
    }
}
```

And added Dependency Injection in ConfigureServices method in ASP.NET CORE startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IDocumentExecuter, MyDocumentExecuter>();
```

Now everthing works.